# " fatal error C1083: Cannot open compiler generated file: '': Invalid argument" while trying to "pip install robotframework-confluentkafkalibrary"

Tags: visual-studio-2019, robotframework, confluent-kafka-python

I am trying to install robotframework-confluentkafkalibrary using command `pip install robotframework-confluentkafkalibrary` during which i get the following error :

---

```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\user 1\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\user 1\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\RdKafka\include /TcC:\Users\user 1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4435vdy_\confluent-kafka_8e3e9105570c4a34af052530bef5473e\confluent_kafka\src\Admin.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\Users\user 1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4435vdy_\confluent-kafka_8e3e9105570c4a34af052530bef5473e\confluent_kafka\src\Admin.obj
  Admin.c
  C:\Users\user 1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4435vdy_\confluent-kafka_8e3e9105570c4a34af052530bef5473e\confluent_kafka\src\Admin.c : fatal error C1083: Cannot open compiler generated file: '': Invalid argument
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for confluent-kafka
  Running setup.py clean for confluent-kafka
```

---

I am using Visual Studio 2019, confluent-6.2.0, librdkafka-1.7.0-confluent6.2.0, gitBash to run this pip install command.
All the help that i can get is appreciated.